# How to read NT Security Descriptor?

Tags: windows, active-directory, windows-server, windows-security, windows-administration

I have an application that stores object permissions in what they call "NT Security Descriptor"

I'm not sure if this is some windows standard. It looks like this:

> 0x04000000001C00000000000000000000000000000000000105000000000005150000006A5B007F2501AD5CA912B91E16E400000100000000001C000000000003310F00010500000000000515000000F4680D03A5124B6B881C6A372E290000

How can I read it? I know there must be SIDs of AD users and stuff inside.

Edit: At the end I want to find duplicates. I have thousands of permissions and I know many (most) are equal. But the binaries are not identical.

Comment: some partial data, look like 2 ACL. for `S-1-5-21-51210484-1800082085-929701000-10542` with access `f3103` and another sid `S-1-5-21-2130729834-1554841893-515445417-58390`

Comment: That's right. How did you do it? I need to read thousands of these.